# The questions that have a historical lock are still visible in the lists

Tags: bug, status-review, questions

I have [historical-locked a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-things-should-an-indie-game-developer-never-do), and it's still visible from a [/question list](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes); however, it's written [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/303557) that it should not be visible:

> Additionally, on main (non-meta) sites, historically locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists),

Is it possible to fix it (by hiding the question from the list)?

I thought I kept on seeing it in the list because I'm a mod and have super powers (), but looking at the list with an anonymous window/user, I still see it.

Comment: (For reference, my earlier edit was to ensure that this issue was properly tracked internally and could be forwarded to the relevant developer team to follow up, since this bug report is still valid.)